Request Header Fields Too Large at Request.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors.0babdcb6.bundle.js:196939:19)
Request Header Fields Too Large. can't make api calls due to this issue, is it related to webpack configuration or something else because with same in react 16 and webpack 4 it is working.
output: {
pathinfo: true,
path: path.resolve(__dirname, paths.appPublic),
filename: 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].bundle.js', // Add contenthash for uniqueness
publicPath: publicPath,
chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js', // Add contenthash for uniqueness
devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
  path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),

},
optimization: {
moduleIds: 'deterministic',
runtimeChunk: 'single',
splitChunks: {
cacheGroups: {
vendor: {
test: /[\/]node_modules[\/]/,
name: 'vendors',
chunks: 'all',
},
},
},
minimizer: [
// For webpack@5 you can use the ... syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. terser-         webpack-plugin), uncomment the next line
...,
new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
],
},
//here is the complete error
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Request Header Fields Too Large
at Request. (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors.0babdcb6.bundle.js:196939:19)
at push.66837.Emitter.emit (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors.0babdcb6.bundle.js:4007:20)
at xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors.0babdcb6.bundle.js:197211:10)
